# I want to show the total number of catalogues available for each stores on the side of the store name using vue js using an array

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Mind you I am trying query data from my database

So this is my vue code

Stores
                                        
                                    
                                       {{store.name}} - ({{store.catalogues}})

I even tried using this piece of code ( {{ store.name }}: {{ store.catalogues.length }} )  but it still returns nothing but only the store name.

It is returning 0 number of catalogues on each and every store even the ones with catalogues

I wanted it to return the number of catalogues in brackets on the side of each store name

Comment: Where and how do you assign the response to `catalogues`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your store name and no of catalogues statement into a div or p tag and then try, it works for me
Stores {{store.name}} - ({{ store.catalogues }})